# Monotone Convergence Theorem and Completeness of measurable space

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am reading about the monotone convergence theorem which states:

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ a complete measurable space.

If $f_n\rightarrow f$ monotone increasing and for almost all $x\in D$ then

$\int_Ef_n dx\rightarrow \int_E f$ for every measurable set $E$.

So, this theorem is also valid for not complete measurable spaces but then we must have $f_n\rightarrow f$ for **all** $x\in D$. I can not read from the prove why this is true. Can someone explain?

Comment: What is $D$ in this context?

Comment: I think it should be X instead of D..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that by $D$, you meant $X$.

The issue is a technical one on the way we defined "almost everywhere".  If  $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ is not complete, we say that a property P(x) is true "almost everywhere" if there is a set $N \in \Sigma$ such that $\mu(N)=0$ and $\{x\in X\: :\: P(x) \textrm { is false }\} \subseteq N$. Note that the set $\{x\in X\: :\: P(x) \textrm { is false }\}$ may not be measurable.

If $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ is not complete, we may have a sequence of measurable functions $f_n$ converging monotonically to $f$ almost everywhere, but $f$ not being measurable.

Let us see an example. If $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ is not complete, there is a set $N \in \Sigma$ such that $\mu(N)=0$ and a set $A \subseteq N$ such that $A \notin \Sigma$. Take, for all $n$, $f_n=0$  and take $f=\chi_A$. Then $f_n\rightarrow f$ monotone increasing almost everywhere. But $f$ is NOT measurable and $\int_X f$ is not defined.